# Cloud Firestore: Retrieve dynamic field keys with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am sending a notification using a device token with Cloud Firestore and Cloud Function. Now the system will store the device token in which user logs in. Since a user may have multiple device or may logged in using different device, all I want is to send this notification to those device using the stored device token. This is how a users document looks like, I store the tokens as a nested object.

```
{
name: "Frank Kemerut",
device_tokens: { 23qweq: "LG G6", Os23pk: "Samsung S6", asd231: "Samsung S9" },
age: 12
}
```

Now I want to iterate and get all key and value then send a notification to those device using the collected tokens. How am I going to perform this? Is this the best approach?

Comment: Do you want to send a notification to all this tokens(devices) when a certain event occurred using cloud functions right?

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged yes

Comment: OK I will answer it using Typescript assuming its  a firestore trigger is that will work with you?

Comment: I am using Javascipt, is it far different?

Comment: No very small different you can convert it pretty easy

Comment: Okay let me try it

Comment: When you send a notification after a trigger you will have a user id or something to access that tokens right?

Comment: Yup, I can already get other fields except with this nested object.

Comment: Cool so i will assume you get the userId some how and you will make an extra query in that cloud function to get the user document then get those token

Comment: Yeah all I need is the code snippet for that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here is a cloud function that will send a notification to all user devices when a firestore event triggered. Assuming you have the user id in that trigger from the event object or another way. The function will use that id to get the user document from the database depending on how you stored it then get the notification token and send it to all of his devices in the `device_tokens` map

```
export const sendEventNotification = functions.firestore.document('events/${eventId}')
    .onCreate((data, context) => {
        const userId = "someId"
        //Get the user document to get the notification tokens.
        return firestore.doc(`users/${userId}`).get().then((user) => {

            //dummy notification payload
            const payload = {
                data: {
                    event: JSON.stringify(data.data())
                }
            }

            //The device tokens mapped to device name.
            const device_tokens = user.data().device_tokens

            //Array of notification tokens that we will send a notification to.
            const promises = []
            Object.keys(device_tokens).forEach(token => {
                promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload))
            })

            return Promise.all(promises)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Failed to send user notification. Error: ${error}`)
            return null
        })
})
```

Comment: Can I directly put admin messaging inside foreach loop without doing promises?

Comment: No, you need to add promises because it's an async function

Comment: Okay thank you I will try it now  and if it works I will immediately accept this answer.

Comment: What if the device_tokens is empty how am I going to handle that?

Comment: Yes, you should check if the key is not empty before you call promise.push I forgot to add it. And accept the question if the solution work with you :)

Comment: It is working fine thanks, now I have new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130011/cloud-firestore-function-javascript-triggering-a-function-with-whereequalto-que