# Cloud Firestore Function Javascript: Triggering a function with whereEqualTo query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In Android we can listen inside a collection with simple queries/compound queries by setting a query like this.

```
mQuery = mDatabase.collection("Users")
            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .collection("Request").whereEqualTo("status","received")
            .whereEqualTo("type","friend_request")
            .orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(5);
```

Then setting a listener based on that Query like this.

```
 mQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            //If something went wrong
            if (e != null)
                Log.w(TAG, "ERROR : ", e);...//foreach loop
```

Can I do similar things with Cloud Function? I am currently using this line of code and it is working.

```
functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onCreate((added, context) => {
```

But for some changes, now I would like to trigger a function only where document field is equal to something then foreach loop I think?

Another thing is how am I going to get the document Id of 'Notification' collection now if queries is possible, now I use wild card then retrieving it like this.

```
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
```

Comment: Like the answer said you will length to all the changes and only process the data that meet with your conditions.

Comment: But this will cost me more for every trigger events including for those that not meet my condition specially if subscribed to a plan like Blaze?

Comment: Man first 2 million invocations are free and every new million invocation will cost you 0.4$ It's very cheap. So it won't affect you as you think.

Comment: Thanks for that info. could  you give me a reference for that and  other billings?

Comment: For cloud functions pricing https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing for all prices https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cloud Functions triggers for Firestore, you can only specify which collections and documents cause the function to fire by using wildcards.  There are no query filters available.  If you want to further restrict which changed documents require some action, you have to check the contents of the document in your code.

Comment: In other words, all I can do is to listen to all newly added document and it depend on me if I am going to response or do further more if field value is met or not?